# issues with aacplayer and mobile provider

Tags: android, mobile, proxy

Hi i have my application aacplayer works awesome using wifi and mobile data, but specifically in my country i have two providers, in one works good using their data service but in the second provider im getting 502 bad gateway error here my Logcat of Eclipse in the provider #1 you could see 502 bad gateway and provider #2 ICY 200 OK

```
 PROVIDER #1:                          07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=null, val=HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway             07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=Content-Language, val=en             07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=Content-Type, val=text/html;charset=utf-8             07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=MiepId, val=HTS_responseError502BadGateway_1             07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=X-Android-Received-Millis, val=1373647677389             07-12 11:47:57.386: D/AACPlayer(28611): header: key=X-Android-Sent-Millis, val=1373647675513             07-12 11:47:57.386: W/MultiPlayer(28611): Content type not audio: text/html;charset=utf-8             07-12 11:47:57.386: W/MultiPlayer(28611): Content type not recognized             07-12 11:47:57.386: E/MultiPlayer(28611): Could not recognize the type of the stream.             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611): playAsync():             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not recognize the type of the stream.             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611):     at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer.processHeaders(MultiPlayer.java:139)             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611):     at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:280)             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611):     at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:248)             07-12 11:47:57.391: E/AACPlayer(28611):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

         

                      PROVIDER #2:                  07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=null, val=ICY 200 OK         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=content-type, val=audio/aacp         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-br, val=64         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-genre, val=Variado         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-metaint, val=32768         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-name, val=www.streaming507.com         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-notice1, val=<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-notice2, val=SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-pub, val=1         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=icy-url, val=www.streaming507.com         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=X-Android-Received-Millis, val=1373648175281         07-12 11:56:15.276: D/AACPlayer(15125): header: key=X-Android-Sent-Millis, val=1373648175135         07-12 11:56:15.281: I/MultiPlayer(15125): Setting AAC decoder for content type audio/aacp         07-12 11:56:15.281: I/AACPlayer(15125): The dynamic metainfo is sent every 32768 bytes         07-12 11:56:15.281: D/BufferReader(15125): init(): capacity=5600         07-12 11:56:15.281: D/BufferReader(15125): run()
```

Maybe provider #1 is blocking something ? my IP maybe? because the shoutcast server is on my IP and on my app also.

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure types of stream in both examples are equal ? 1. java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not recognize the type of the stream. 2. Setting AAC decoder for content type audio/aacp

Comment: use something like this to watch what data you're receiving and posting http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=585642. it's just not enough info to answer

Comment: yes but in provider #1 i got that issue and my app doesnt work, i talk with the provider they think they have apn issues they set a kind of proxy in their apn settings and maybe thats is blocking my app